# HighCharts Errorbar with irregular time series interval

Tags: highcharts, time-series, timeserieschart

i'm trying to build a spline with an errorbar with xAxis based on irregular time instead of using categories but i got some troubles.

This is an example:  http://jsfiddle.net/Zj2Lp/4/

Any idea how to achieve that?

Thank you in advance

Code here:

```
var chart;
$(function() {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
        zoomType: 'xy',
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Temperature vs Rainfall'
    },
    xAxis: [{
        type: 'datetime'
    }],
    /*
    xAxis: [{
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    }],
    */
    yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        labels: {
            format: '{value} °C',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Temperature',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            }
        }
    }],
    tooltip: {
        shared: true
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 10), 7.0], 
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 11), 26.5], 
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 12), 9.6]
        ],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '<span style="font-weight: bold; color: {series.color}">{series.name}</span>: <b>{point.y:.1f}°C</b> '
        }
    }, {
        name: 'Temperature error',
        type: 'errorbar',
        data: [
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 10), [6, 8]], 
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 11), [26.1, 27.8]], 
            [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 12), [7.6, 10.0]]
        ],
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '(error range: {point.low}-{point.high}°C)<br/>'
        }
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the format you've used for the `data` in your `errorbar` series. The correct format is using a two-dimensional array. Not a three dimensional array, like you use in your code.

You had each point in the series being:

```
[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 10), [6, 8]]
```

It should be:

```
[Date.UTC(2014, 5, 10), 6, 8]
```

Here's the final updated `errorbar` series:

```
{
    name: 'Temperature error',
    type: 'errorbar',
    data: [
        [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 10), 6, 8], 
        [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 11), 26.1, 27.8], 
        [Date.UTC(2014, 5, 12), 7.6, 10.0]
    ],
    tooltip: {
        pointFormat: '(error range: {point.low}-{point.high}°C)<br/>'
    }
}
```

And [here's a updated JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Zj2Lp/6/) to see the result.